# Scala.js crossProject vs manual setup

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

To compile the same source code with Scala.js and Scala JVM the [documentation](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/cross-build.html) says to use crossProject, for instance

```
lazy val foo = crossProject.in(file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "foo",
    version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  )

lazy val fooJVM = foo.jvm
lazy val fooJS = foo.js
```

However it looks that the same goal can be achieved setting up the modules manually

```
lazy val fooSettings = Seq(
  name := "foo",
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "shared" / "src" / "main" / "scala"
)

lazy val fooJVM = project.in(file("jvm"))
  .settings(fooSettings: _*)

lazy val fooJS = project.in(file("js"))
  .settings(fooSettings: _*)
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
```

Does `crossProject` do something important or it's just more convenient way to setup stuff?

Comment: please see this discussion... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-js/SSKxkxvL5bo/qsJD8pmWyLQJ "depending on the cross projects will not work properly"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, in your manual setup, you have *separate* jvm and js subdirectories under your "shared" area -- it doesn't look like they're the same code at all.

CrossProject is about letting you have a single directory structure, with the *same* code, that is compiled for *both* sides. Possibly with some small subdirectories that are specific to one side or another, but in general the focus is that most of the code is shared -- the jvm and js subdirectories, if present (it depends on the mode), are usually just shims to adapt the common code to those sides.

All that said, it *is* really just to make it more convenient -- I believe you could achieve the same results without CrossProject. But in the common case where you're sharing a lot of code, it's significantly more convenient...

Comment: > It looks like, in your manual setup, you have separate jvm and js subdirectories under your "shared" area < If you're not sure, you can check. In my tests they are the same dir.